# Rename subdirectory files with specific extention to parent folder's name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a number of folders where I need to rename some of the files inside with a specific extension i.e. '.jpeg' to the name of the parent folder plus its existing name.

```
META_10234
--- file1.jpeg
--- file2.jpeg

META2_10235
--- file1.jpeg
--- file2.jpeg
```

Desired output:

```
META_10234
---META_10234_file1.jpeg
---META_10234_file2.jpeg
```

I've tried doing something like this:

```
for file in $(ls | grep 'META_*'); do mv "./$file/*.jpeg" "./$f/$f*_.jpeg"; done;
```

The error is:

```
mv ./META_10234/.jpeg: No such file or directory
```

How can I match any file inside the subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward.
No need for the `ls`/`grep`, just use a simple glob - and you do need the loop but remember you are renaming files individually, not *en masse*.

```
$: key="${PWD##*/}"
$: for f in *.jpeg; do mv "$f" "${key}_$f"; done
```

`$PWD` is the currently logged directory.
[Bash parameter parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) uses `#` to remove the glob pattern from the front of the string. `##` makes it "greedy", matching the most it can rather than the least. That means `"${PWD##*/}"` removes as much as it can from the front of the value until it sees a `/` (i.e., the leading path), leaving only the name of the current directory.

There are other ways with other tools, but unless you have a zillion this will handle it fine.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you mind explaining what the ##*/ do?

Comment: Thank you so much Paul. I really appreciate your explanation!